# RouteObserver for GoRouter to catch go/goNamed transitions

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, observers, flutter-go-router

I have been analyzing different navigator observers by 3rd party integrations (e.g., [`SentryNavigatorObserver`](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dart/blob/main/flutter/lib/src/navigation/sentry_navigator_observer.dart), [`FirebaseAnalyticsObserver`](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics/lib/observer.dart)) to make identical for tools that don't have it by default. But I noticed that neither of these is really catching all route transitions. I see it when they display data in their corresponding consoles. Yes, it works with `push`/`pop`, but any transitions within the same level with `go` are not being tracked. Which is very annoying. Anybody knows the way to solve it?

---

For example,

The transition from `/page` to `/page/detail` is observed.

The transition from `/pageA` to `/pageB` is not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the issue. Some of the root routes were built using `pageBuilder` and `NoTransitionPage`, so to avoid animation, since they are working as tabs.

But besides setting `NoTransitionPage.key` initializer argument, you also need to set `NoTransitionPage.name` for the routes to be recognized.

So, because I did not do that, the navigator saw all these routes as `null`, so it just didn't see them changing in between.

---

Example how it should be:

```
GoRoute(
    name: Routes.home,
    path: Routes.getPathNamed(Routes.home),
    pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage<void>(
      key: state.pageKey, // <--- note this
      name: state.name, // <--- note this
      child: ScaffoldWithBottomBarNav(body: Routes.getPageNamed(Routes.home)),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 20):

**Extend `Observer` from `NavigatorObserver`**

---

**Code**

```
 GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  observers: [
    GoRouterObserver(),  Specify your observer here
  ],
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      ...
    )
    GoRoute(
      ...
    ),
  ],
);

class GoRouterObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    print('MyTest didPush: $route');
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    print('MyTest didPop: $route');
  }

  @override
  void didRemove(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    print('MyTest didRemove: $route');
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route<dynamic>? newRoute, Route<dynamic>? oldRoute}) {
    print('MyTest didReplace: $newRoute');
  }
}
```

Comment: "+1" Thanks, this information is difficult to find in the docs. With this solution you can see when routes are pushed/popped/removed. I can now use this to track page/route views with google analytics, grabbing the name of the requested route by using 'route.settings.name' and passing it to my google analytics widget as a custom event (eg "page_clicked", params {"page_name":route.settings.name}

Comment: I saw this answer many times, can you please add a more concrete example?